How to create dynamic type based on other values using typescript?
I have this code in my angular
@Input() id: string = '_id';

@Input() name: string = 'name';

@Input() items: Item<this['id'], this['name']>[] = [];

How can i create type for items based on id and name?
if id === '_id' and name === 'name' so type for items should be
{_id: string; name: string}[]
if id === 'identifier' and name === 'title' so type for items should be
{identifier: string; title: string}[]
i have tried to use something like this:
type Item<ID extends string, Name extends string> = {
  [key in ID | Name]: string;
};

@Input() items: Item<this['id'], this['name']>[] = [];

but have no result

This question is similar to: How do I dynamically assign properties to an object in TypeScript?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

The only way to do this is to make your class generic, so each instance of the class has a fixed id and name value, as shown in this playground link; Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?
